# Calling error component from sightly java

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6

I have a sightly java class(a java class included inside component) which calls an api and checks whether the response in null. If its null, I have to call the error component. When I am setting the response status as 404, it is not working because before executing that line, it is taking the response as 200. How to call the error component in this case.
Note: I have tried redirecting the URL to error.html, but thats not the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally bad practice to redirect or change the response status from a component/view as the response might already have some content that was committed.

You might want to redesign you application to either:

1. Call the remote API at the beginning of the request handling and, if the remote API returns null, return a 404 before anything else is committed to the response.
2. Handle the null response from the remote API by either:

   - Rendering an appropriate response, in case the null response is expected/permitted in some cases.
   - Throwing an exception, which will result in status 500, in case the null response is not expected.

Comment: thanks. But I am confused when you say "Call the remote API at the beginning of the request handling". The flow is like this
1. a wrong page is called which doesnt exist
2. it goes to its parent's page's component
3. page component have a sightly java class which calls the api to verify if the page exists or not(as these pages are dynamic pages)
4. if it exists, show it, if not redirect to 404 error page

I can not set the response status at step 4 as the resp is already committed. I can not do it in step 3 as I can able to know its existence by calling api.
So which step you suggest?

Comment: @SkepticScribbler perhaps in your situation it might work to have a special servlet or filter that handles/intercepts the request and checks the dynamic API/content. Other idea would be to define your custom page helper/Use Object that is invoked before anything is rendered and can handle the redirect.

Comment: it will be really helpful if you can point me to some article/url. As I am new to this, I have understood what you are saying but have no knowledge how to implement it. The second idea suits to the situation in hand but when I am doing getResponse().sendRedirect, it works well but it changes the URL which should not happen. I am grateful for your time and response till now anyway!